# Why might the same source code give different results on another machine? JQuery datepicker UI Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, datepicker

could really use some pointers from an experienced datepicker user.

I have a gridview in an ASP.net webform.  One column of the grid is composed of both an asp:label and an input type="hidden" control.

I have managed to get a datepicker to appear in every row of this column and for the date of each datepicker to be set by the value of the  control (a list of dates). The label shows the same data as text. When I click on an icon in the row the datepicker appears showing the same date as the label text.  This is great.  The problem is when my firends run the exact same sourcecode with everything identical the datepickers are stuck showing only todays date in every datepicker!? All the id names and fields are the same - same datasource for the dates to be shown, everything is identical as far as I can see but the correct dates only appear on my laptop.

Here is the code for the datepicker:

```
       $(function () {
                      $(".picker").datepicker({
                              showOn: "button",
                              buttonImage: "/images/calendar2.png",
                              buttonImageOnly: true,
                              buttonText: "calender"
                              });
                              $(".picker").datepicker("setDate", $(".picker"))
                              });
```

And here is the code for the HTML column:

```
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Date")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>'      Height="15%">      </asp:Label>
      <input type="hidden" class="picker" id="datepicker" 
 value='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Date")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>'/>   
      </ItemTemplate>
```

Any help greatly appreciated - i'm pulling my hair out

All the same Js files are present in the same locations on all machines and the datepicker works as expected on all machines except when it comes to setting the date form the input control value.

Comment: Hopefully a dumb question but... Did you clear your cache locally when you refreshed? Are they using different browsers than you are?

Comment: Same browsers, all chrome.  Clearing the cache might be an idea though - is this the browser cache you mean? If so I'm pretty sure none of us did this.  Could that affect a JQuery widget having it's date set by a datasource that come from a database though?

Comment: If you've been developing on your machine and have made some changes that weren't picked cause of chrome caching your JS file... Not sure, just throwin' darts here.

Comment: Easiest way to clear your cache is to open dev console (f12) then right click refresh button in chrome

Comment: Also, yeah, what calls are you making to a DB? Are you hitting a webservice?

Comment: I run a query to an Azure SQL database to fetch the data for the gridview.  Everyone gets the same data no problems and the label text for the same column that the datapicker is in is displayed the same with the same formatting for all machines.  I'll definitley get the others to try clearing the cache.

Comment: I spent quite a long time looking and comparing the code on the other machines today and they didn't seem to be missing any of the changes I had made.  All the Js scripts and css files were there.  There aren't really that many lines of code so I'm pretty sure I didn't miss anything.  The datepicker plugin loads fine on the other machines and I tested harcoding a date with the "setDate" function and that worked too.  It seems to be an issue recognizing the input field, but the id of the input field is the same and the data is the same.

Comment: Is your friend's computer set to a culture with a different date format?  E.g. dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Thats a possibility, although I explicitly format the date  before passing it to the datepicker and I'm fairly sure the datepickers format is decided by the datepicker - at least hardcoding the datepicker date with a string worked in the same way on all computers.

Comment: Wow! Thanks John Wu - it was the culture settings - thanks again :D